# About CSS li tag word break

Tags: css

I want to ask about how to solve this problem when I doing the sub-menu and one subtitle is too long, the word will overlap with the second column subtitle as the photo I attached below, what should I do. I have to try to change the width, but the interface become not nice, so I think the word break may help but the word break not really working. I have to try put the word break in the tag

or in the tag  even in the tag , but all give me the same result as the image.

```
<li style="word-break: break-all;">
  <a class="" href="e-wallet-tranfer.php">YoudePay Registration Wallet</a>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: I have try put the word break in tag a or in tag li even in tag ul , but all give me same result as the image.

Comment: It looks like there is an fixed `height` value is mentioned either in li or a...so try to remove it...

Comment: Can you provide working code ?

Comment: as @Bhuwan said..try removing height value..also try to use <br> if it works.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code - HTML and CSS, and maybe JavaScript, that you believe affect the outcome. With only a screenshot, we cannot help, and giving advice based on assumptions is probably not very helpful.

Comment: @Bhuwan Thanks， solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used specific `height` in `li` or `a` elements,
If the `height` is used, remove it ‍and using `line-height`.

I hope your problem will be resolved.